# URL rewriting in Cake

Tags: cakephp, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite URL in my cake application in such a way that only slug (e.g. title) is shown in the URL. For example, if I have a cake URL like www.site.com/users/view/1 (controller/action/ID), I need to show only /vikram.sinha if the user's nick is vikram.sinha (no ID, no action, no controller or anything else in the URL).

I am making sure that the title (slug) is unique before storing and the best I could do is the following.

www.site.com/profile/vikram.sinha by adding the route below.

```
Router::connect('/profile/:slug', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'),
        array(
            'pass' => array('slug'),
        ));
```

The problem I am facing is I also need to remove profile from the URL. Couldn't find a way to rewrite URL in cake without adding something before slug.

Or may be the URL can be rewritten using htaccess directly but I am not good with that either. If someone is suggesting using htaccess then please assume that the URL need to be changed is www.site.com/users/view/vikram.sinha

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing it without /profile in there? And just doing /:slug

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet IMO is to do something like reddit where each slug is prefixed with /r/.

Example:

```
mysite.com/u/johnsmith
```

Then, in your routes, you can do something like this:

```
Router::connect('/u/:slug/*', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'view'), 
    array('pass'=>array('slug')));
```

If you really don't want to do that, you can use something like:

```
Router::connect('/:slug/*', array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'view'), 
    array('pass'=>array('slug')));
```

But keep in mind, any other controllers, plugins...etc etc etc will need their own routes, since it will think that ANYTHING passed after the mysite.com/ is a uname. Not the best idea IMO.

Comment: Yep! I will go with the second option. Certainly not the best but I am dealing with a client who doesn't take "no" for an answer so I have no choice. Thanks.